# Как починить буфер обмена в VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, alpine-linux

Как починить буфер обмена в VirtualBox?
Виртуальная машина - AlpineLinux.
Общие папки работают, а буфер обмена - нет.
virtualbox-guest-additions и virtualbox-guest-additions_virt ставил.
Что делать? Как чинить?

ps: буфер я так и не починил, но решил проблему путем подключения по ssh.

там вставка работает нормально.

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, а вы после установки `virtualbox-guest-additions` заходили в "Устройства > Общий буфер обмена" и ставили там режим работы буфера?

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus, ставил, двунаправленный. нашел ответ на тостере, где в комментариях написано, что нельзя в терминал напрямую вставлять из хост-ос. это так?

Comment: А для вставки и копирования данных вы пользуетесь ctrl+c/ctrl+v на машине? Может просто кнопки конфликтуют, так как VirtualBox ставит по дефолту на, кажется правый, ctrl снятие фокуса с окна

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus, lctrl+shift+v

Comment: А простым правым кликом > Вставить у вас получится вставить данные? Я вот на своем ПК на убунте запустил в виртуалке live образ Bodhi linux и даже без всяких дополнений буфер сработал. Что у вас за система стоит, какая на виртуалке?

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus, ui-less alpine linux

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97723/discussion-between-nonforgivingjesus-and-dasauser).

Comment: Общий буфер обмена скорее всего работает только в Xorg, а не в терминале